# iOS : C to iOS of static const char array gives error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I had some legacy C code (not written by me! I don't know C), which I had to import to an iPhone App am writing. The .h file of the C code has this:

> static const char rcd_db_h[] = "$Id: sqlservicedb.h,v 1.100.2.1
>   2009/07/07 12:31:45 fre01 Exp $";

When I compile in XCode (iOS 5.1, XCode 4.5.2), this line throws the error "Expected identifier or '('". I tried various ways to avert this : Googl'ing, adding escape '\' characters, replacing double quote with single quote, adding a * to make it 'static const char *'. All in vain. Please help!

Comment: that's strange, sure that this line causes the problem?

Comment: If you comment out the line in question (it's not useful without CVS anyway), does any following line start giving errors?

Comment: good question, peko. Now that you said this : I recollect that I have been running with this same .h file with no errors for the past 20 days or more! Today seems to be an all-error day! I have been getting all strange errors since afternoon (finally found they we due to cyclic reference of classes and resolved them), and that's when this error (which never showed up for almost a month!) popped up! Any idea how I can go about fixing it? Some stale code/binary used by XCode? I tried cleaning up XCode, deleting the directories from Terminal, restarting machine...nothing works.

Comment: Yes Jaochim, the next line right after the one showing the error is this (which uses the constant and so I cannot comment it out): static const void *const no_unused_dbservice_warn[] = { rcd_db_h, no_unused_dbservice_warn };

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had inserted '(' by mistake in the file! Oh my! My whole day got wasted. Thanks to all of you for your help! Fixed it now!